# Increasing the noise of an existing backend

Tags: qiskit

if I am trying to increase the noise of an existing backend provided from qiskit fakeprovider, which way would be best to approach it:

Increasing readout error or increasing the quantum error or both?

Thanks

Comment: One option could be create your own custom noise model: https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/3_building_noise_models.html But I'm not sure if that's the questions you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easiest to do with the `BackendV2` providers (so things classes `FakeHanoiV2` or `FakeAuckland`). To adjust the error rates for operations in the backend you can modify the target in place. So something like:

```
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeHanoiV2
backend = FakeHanoiV2()
backend.target['measure'][(0,)].error = 0.5
```

would change the error rate of measurement on qubit 0 in the backend object to 50%. You can do this for any operation on the backend (the first key is the operation name and the second key is the qubits it operates on as a tuple). This will then be used when creating a noise model from the backend (either via `AerSimulator.from_backend()` or `NoiseModel.from_backend()` with qiskit-aer>=0.11.2). The `.run()` method does this internally when qiskit-aer is installed but doing the inplace modification like this will not reflect in the noise model used for simulation currently (it is waiting on https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/8979 to fix this).

Comment: Hello, are there any other operations in the first key which can be used to add error, I am struggling to find the documentation of the backend.target online. Thanks!

Comment: You can look at `target.operation_names` to get a list of all the operations in a target. Note that no all operations necessarily need to exist on every qubit (although in practice for all the current fake backends operations are available on all qubits).